# Where does all my rep go?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

This is starting to puzzle me a bit: I've asked 2 questions which have gotten a combined 11 upvotes.

I've made 10 answers, for a total of 25 upvotes. (Some of them in CW threads, but not all)

So why do I have only 131 rep? Is this a bug or some hidden feature I'm not aware of? Is rep counted differently on "meta beta" sites?

(I'm tagging this as `[bug]` for now. Feel free to retag it if there's a sane explanation for my missing rep)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Visit these sites:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/reputation
https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/reputation
to view your reputation audit.

From [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation/43005#43005), the numbers can be interpreted as follows:

The **first number** is the vote type, where common vote types are:

- 1 = accepted answer (to or from you)
- 2 = upvote (to you)
- 3 = downvote (to or from you)
- 8 = bounty grant (from you)
- 9 = bounty award (to you)
- 16 = edit suggestion approved

The **second number** is the post ID that the vote was on. Remember that votes on community wiki posts do *not* generate rep, so those votes will not appear here. (Note that some vote types like offensive, spam, and bounties apply to any post regardless of its community wiki status)

The **third number** is the value of the vote. Note that the value may be capped if you reach the daily upvote reputation limit. If the value is capped, it will appear in brackets like `[3]` so.

The **date boundaries** are printed whenever your reputation changed in a given day(s). It contains the current date, the amount your rep changed (up or down) since the last time, and the total amount of rep you have earned to date.

Answer (score 10):

Reputation isn't counted on meta.  Your reputation score on meta is that from the main site (slurped in every hour, I think).  Looking at your profile there, I'm figuring that you started on 101 (do you have a decent reputation on SO?) and then got three upvotes for your answer.  Hence 131.

(NB This is just about *reputation*, I think.  Badges are separated, as is the '% acceptance' bit)

Comment: ooh, that makes sense. Thanks. :)